# check the activity run

Tags: android

for example my App have 3 activity main Activity A,and other B ,C,so i want to know if i can know B or C Activity is running,i know how to check  Main Activity A using PackageManager. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ActivityManager to get information about running activities.

Comment: i want to know B or c ,not the main A,i can use the  ActivityManager to get the A

Answer (score -2):

We can use **Toast.maketext** to know the Activity B or C is started or not

Comment: i mean that; put the Toast.maketext in Activity B ou Activity C.